# Best practice to present math and text in aligned structure with different consecutive environments

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath, text-mode

I would like to ask your opinion on the best way to present aligned structured math and text content within different environments, for instance:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain} \newtheorem{ass}{Assumption}[chapter]
\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\tran}{^{\mkern-1.5mu\mathsf{T}}}
\newcommand{\gaussian}[2]{\mathcal{G}\left({#1},{#2}\right)}
\newcommand{\expected}[1]{\mathbb{E}\left[{#1}\right]}

\begin{document}

 \begin{ass} This is the long assumption:
  \begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
    \expected{\matr{a}_k} &= \matr{0},\;\forall k \qquad&& \text{(very short text)}\\
    \expected{\matr{b}_k \matr{b}_l\tran} &= \matr{I}\times\matr{B}\times\matr{I}\footnote{this is a footnote example},\;\forall k,l \qquad&& \text{(this is a long long long long text)}
    \end{align}
  \end{subequations}
\end{ass}

\begin{ass} This is the short assumption:
  \begin{align}
    \matr{c}_k &\sim \gaussian{\matr{\mu_{\matr{c}}}}{\Sigma_{\matr{c}}} \qquad&& \text{(this is a short text)}
  \end{align}
\end{ass}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

What I don't really like is the different/inconsistent spacing between the two different environments. Do you have any suggestions to present the content in a nicer way?

Comment: The example just produces `! Undefined control sequence. <argument>  \expected`

Comment: You probably want to use `alignat` to control the space between the equations and the descriptions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle edited with a new definition for the control sequence

Comment: @egreg Already tried but I don't like to handpick the space manually. What if I change my mind later or add shorter and longer environments here and there. It would be a pain. I understand if that is the simplest solution, just wondering if I can get a nicer one.